# Javascript Toggle custom button with jquery Reel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I want to make a button for jquery reel, the problem now is if you want to change the image you need to click on 2 different buttons.
I'm a noob at javascript and can't seem to change the script to work
Can someone help me do a on click toggle between this 2 functions?

```
  $('#nonUV').click(function(){
   $('#image').reel('images', 'LamborghiniGallardo/turntable###.jpg|000..059');
  });

  $('#UV').click(function(){
    $('#image').reel('images', 'LamborghiniGallardoUV/turntable###.jpg|000..059');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to keep track of the current state and toggle it on every click:

```
var state = false;

$('#singleButton').click(function(){
    if(!state){
        $('#image').reel('images', 'LamborghiniGallardo/turntable###.jpg|000..059');
    }
    else {
        $('#image').reel('images', 'LamborghiniGallardoUV/turntable###.jpg|000..059');
    }

    state = !state;
});
```